# classic RISC pipeline: Why does memory access stage comes before register file write back?

Tags: pipeline, risc-v, register-file, risc

Here are two confusions:

1. Instruction fetch step provides info on what's the op and in which register the data lies, but how does that data comes into those registers?
2. It seems that once the execution is done by the ALU, the register write back stage should be the next and then that reg file data is mapped back to the memory outside the processor.

Please do enhance the knowledge and correct any mistakes.

Comment: How is the result of a fetch supposed to be stored into a register if memory access happens after write back?

Comment: Answer (1) : by previous instructions.

Comment: @user_1818839 I suspect the OP wants to know how the previous instruction then does it. In the case of RISC-V, it's done with LUI and ADDI, if the constant to be loaded is to fill the entire register. And there's others for the case of loading PC relative with AUIPC.

Comment: Lousycoder, you need to show us what you imagine as an alternative that would work or else draw out your case with a specific RISC-V implementation. I've seen a nine stage pipeline, for example. So I need to see what you are looking at, specifically, to walk you through the details and perhaps help with a more serious answer. Regardless, it all does make sense. The problem is in knowing what's in your head.

Comment: Lousycoder, you may also wish to look at [WebRISC-V: Pipelined Datapath Simulation Online](https://webriscv.dii.unisi.it/) and over on the left side load up a pre-canned program to run. If you clock through the process you can see how registers get their values and you will likely see an answer to #2, as well.

Comment: @jonk, Thank you very much for WebRISC-V, I'll come back and explain more clearly about what's my question!

Comment: @lousycoder Best wishes and I look forward to a question where I can consider contributing a thought or two.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for your patience, it seems I need more time & I'll come back within next 2 days.

Comment: @lousycoder I'll look forward to it!

Comment: I'm very sorry, I need more time, I'll comment again once I have done this! Thank You!

Comment: @jonk now going through the RISC-V academic content and WebRISC-V online simulator, it is clear that only load and store instructions can do data memory ops. Due to some vague and generic discussions, I had an impression that any type of RV instruction will have data memory access. I realize that, R, Imm, branch, jump instructions have nothing to do with data memory, right?

Comment: @lousycoder Without pressing myself to scan over the various instructions in more detail again, that's pretty much how I see it. That doesn't yet directly answer your question. But perhaps now you are in a better position to see why the MEM stage is before the WB stage (just look at the LW instruction and follow it through.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at an LW instruction: 0000 0000 0100 0001 0010 0000 1000 0011 (Immediate=4, RS1=2 (SP), RD=1 (RA)):

1. IR: PC is provided to Instruction Memory as a memory address and the instruction is presented at the ReadInstr output.
2. IF/ID: ReadInstr output is latched into the IF/ID latch. At this point the immediate value is extended/expanded by the "immediate generator" and the address (RS1=2) is provided to one of the ports of the dual-read-port register memory. (A dummy value for RS2 of 4 is also provided to the second port, but this read result doesn't matter.) Various slices of the instruction bits are also presented to the input of the ID/EX latch. This is where a lot of decode takes place with parallel units picking off various parts of the latched instruction.
3. ID/EX: The value read from the SP register (2) is latched and presented to the ALU, along with the immediate value of #4 and the "add operation." The ALU presents the sum of the SP register and #4 to its output. The destination register address is also latched here.
4. EX/MEM: The ALU output (SP+4) is latched as the address presented to the Data Memory and the READ control line is activated to perform a read from Data Memory at the presented address. The value read from this address is now presented and ready to be latched at the next step. The destination register address is copied from the ID/EX and latched into EX/MEM, as well.
5. MEM/WB: The destination register address is latched here from the EX/MEM stage and the value read from the Data Memory is latched, as well, and presented back to the register file as a Write Register data value, along with the latched register address that has been copied along through the stages. At the next clock, the presented data value will be written into the addressed register.

If the MEM/WB stage were earlier than the EX/MEM stage, then there would be a serious problem for the LW instruction. The write-back stage would occur too early and the data memory accessed too late.

Comment: Okay, so can I say that reg file read must occur "before" data memory write (in case of Store instruction) and data memory read must occur "before" reg file write (in case of Load instruction), right?

Comment: Usually what I have heard is that RISC based computers copy everything on registers, operate on them and write back the final result to the memory outside the processor. 

Thus, in effect, arithmetic ops like add, mul can't directly access the data memory and the result of these would be stored in reg file which ultimately gets written back to the separate memory using the "store" assembly op. Am I right?

Comment: @lousycoder Don't worry about what you've "heard." RISC is not "a single thing." If you want to see a case where the folks went absolutely ***maximum*** towards RISC then look at the DEC Alpha processor. That baby is absolutely CRAZY-minded towards RISC. The absolute opposite is the MSP430 from TI. They also say the MSP430 is RISC. That's total crap. It isn't even close. So do NOT listen to folks telling you what RISC is and what RISC is not. Only Patterson and Hennessey have the ultimate say on the topic (my opinion.) (I've met both of them.)

Comment: @lousycoder As far as what the SW instruction goes, all it does is use the ALU to compute an address while also passing along a register value. This gets to the Data Memory at the EX/MEM stage, where both the address and the register value are presented to the memory system at thee same time. There's no need for WB here.

Comment: I'm not good at using jargons correctly, by WB I mean that SW instruction performs the write operation to the external memory / or it at least provides the data to be written, right? In this way, we load the particular data using LW instruction, perform any desired math / logical ops or/and use branch/jumps and store the final answer using SW instruction, right?

Comment: @lousycoder The SW instruction provides a pointer register, an immediate offset to add to the pointer register (using the ALU) to create a data memory address, and a register containing the data to write to memory, and then performs that operation. So it doesn't just set things up. It performs the data write before the instruction retires. And yes, there are lots of register operations. But data memory reads and writes are handled with specialized instructions. That said, functional units (and instructions) can be added. So today's boundaries are not tomorrow's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137062/discussion-between-lousycoder-and-jonk).

Comment: @lousycoder I am "working" right now and cannot join an active discussion. In a few hours, yes. Just not now.